# Assigning XML Array Elements to Variable

Tags: arrays, bash

I write bash scripts about once every 5 years, so probably a noob question. This is on OSX.

Paired down script:

```
#!/bin/bash
array=(
  '<item name="Alice" title="President"/>'
  '<item name="Bob" title="CEO"/>'
)

for k in "${array[@]}"; do
  find=${array[$k]}
done
```

Here is the error:
`line 8: <item name="Alice" title="President"/>: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "<item name="Alice" title="President"/>")`

Can't figure this one out. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `k` in the `for` loop holds the element (value) of the array,
not the index. So you need to say:

```
for k in "${!array[@]}"; do
    find="${array[$k]}"
done
```

or

```
for e in "${array[@]}"; do
    find="$e"
done
```

Comment: The first suggestion did not work. Same error. However the second one did. Thanks very much!

Comment: @Cyrus thank you for the elaboration. As you know it is not necessary to double-quote the right-hand variable when assigning to another variable, I'd admit it is a good practice to quote anyway.

Comment: @tshiono: What if array element contains leading or trailing white spaces or consecutive white spaces or a single `*`?

Comment: @Cyrus the mentioned whitespaces are preserved. But a single `*` will make a definitive difference. Understood.